# Show single Magento category on sidebar

Tags: php, model-view-controller, magento, categories

How can I show a single category tree on the sidebar?

Not a product, only the category tree.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Vertical Navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/763/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes) to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The formal way to do this for yourself is to create a module using the Module Creator (search Magento Connect for this) and then:

Create a new phtml file with the following code:

```
$storeCategories = $this->getCats('my-category-url-key');
        foreach ($storeCategories as $category):
            echo '<li><a href="' . $category->getUrl() . '">' . $category->getName() . '</a></li>';
        endforeach;
```

Then a Block called (say) `Namespace_Yourmodule_Block_Singlecat` with the following code:

```
 public function getCats($catName)
 { 
     $parent = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key', $catName)
                    ->getFirstItem();
     return $storeCategories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCategories( $parent->getId(), $recursionLevel=1, $sorted=false, $asCollection=true, $toLoad=false);
}
```

Then you just need to insert the following nodes into `app\design\frontend\yourtheme\layout\yourmodule.xml` layout file:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="yourmodule/singlecat" name="singlecat" template="path/yourfilename.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

Cross your fingers, pray to your deity of choice and Magento may smile upon your code :)